# How to retrieve variables from history.push in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have this function in my main page, pushing searchVal to another page. How can I retrieve and use that value in the other page, which consists of a functional component?

```
const onSearchSubmit = () => {
    history.push(getParamUrl(pages.globalSearch.url, { searchVal }));
};
```

This is the basis of the other page:

```
const GlobalSearchResults = () => {
    const { t } = useTranslation();
    // Set keyboard focus at page title on load
    useEffect(() => {
        document.querySelectorAll<HTMLElement>('h1[tabindex]')[0].focus();
    }, []);


    return (
        <main id="Welcome-component" className="animate__animated animate__fadeIn">
            <h1 tabIndex={0} className="GlobalSearchResults-title">
                {t('GlobalSearchResults-title', 'Search Results')}
            </h1>
            <h5>Search Results for ""</h5>
            
        </main>
    );
};

export default GlobalSearchResults;
```

Comment: can you post the other page code

Comment: yes just posted it

Answer (score 0):

use [withRouter](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/withRouter) to hook router state to your component

```
import { withRouter } from "react-router";


function GlobalSearchResults(props){

   const { match, location, history } = this.props;
   console.log(location); 
   ...
     
}

export default withRouter(GlobalSearchResults)
```

browse location object to see more info